# Embed signature in file with java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I'm trying to find out a way to embed an RSA signature in a file without making it unreadable. For now, I'm able to generate a valid signature as `byte[]` value with my private key.

So now I just want to include it in the file without so I can extract it and verify if the file has been manipulated.

The files that I want to embed signatures into are images, CSS and JavaScript files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My target file is images and javascript's files for example

Comment: What is the file format you want to embed your signature in? UTF-8 text?

Comment: No it's mostly images, css and .js files

Comment: @ArtjomB. Hey, thanks I didn't know about IPTC headers :) Posted as an answer, this is probably as close as we can get...

Comment: Note that the correct tag for RSA signatures and such is [tag:digital-signature], not [tag:signature] which has been taken for method signatures; this is a programming site after all (also @ArtjomB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the file format. For `.css` and `.js` you could think of putting a signature in comments, although a single bit change is already enough to break the signature. So you have to extract the signature perfectly and make sure the `.css` and `.js` files are not converted in any way otherwise. You could also convert the `.css` and `.js` into some *canonical form* and sign that.

For images the trick is more difficult. You would need some kind of meta-data available where you can store the signature. For `.jpeg` or `.png` images that could be an [IPTC attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC_Information_Interchange_Model). These headers are however not present or possible for each image type...

Usually detached signatures are used instead. Detached signatures are for instance defined within the [CMS (cryptographic message syntax) standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852), which in turn is implemented by the [Bouncy Castle libraries](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Comment: Note that relying on verification in JavaScript is probably moot. If you can change the files it is very likely that you can also alter the verification method.

Comment: Do you mean with *detached signatures* that you simply store the signature file alongside of the actual file? The files will be probably sent at some point in time. It may make sense to send the signature alongside of the file in the response headers. Although, this won't be a solution in the browser setting, because JS in the browser doesn't usually have access to the headers.

Comment: - you cannot read the headers from the HTML :) Cookies can be though.